# Is [meek-single-transferable-vote] so distinct as to need a tag separate from [single-transferable-vote]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Concerning the new tags [meek-single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meek-single-transferable-vote) and [strategic-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategic-voting).

Currently the tag "tree" for "scoring votes" (as I see it) is:

| First-level | Second-level | Third-level | Questions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) |  |  | 216 |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [ranked-choice-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranked-choice-voting) |  | 4 |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [range-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range-voting) |  | 4 |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [plurality-voting-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plurality-voting-system) |  | 5 |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [first-past-the-post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-past-the-post) |  | 10 |
| ┗╾╾╾╾ | [single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transferable-vote) |  | 10 |
|  | ┗╾╾╾╾ | [meek-single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meek-single-transferable-vote) | 1 |

Is [meek-single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meek-single-transferable-vote) so distinct as to need a tag separate from [single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transferable-vote)?

Being unfamiliar with Meek STV, I will defer judgment to others.

---

The [strategic-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategic-voting) tag may be added to some of these [five additional "strategic voting" questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22strategic+voting%22+-%5Bstrategic-voting%5D+is%3Aq) and [eleven "tactical voting" questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tactical+voting%22+-%5Bstrategic-voting%5D+is%3Aq).

Of these 16 questions, eight (3 and 5) had the tag added leaving eight (2 and 6) untagged, for "merely mentioning" the terms.

Comment: Could you include an explanation of the differences? I don't think I can make a judgement as of now

Comment: @JoeW - No, I can't explain the differences. I've never answered "vote scoring" questions, because my knowledge of the subject is limited to a general understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is [meek-single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meek-single-transferable-vote) so distinct as to need a tag separate from [single-transferable-vote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transferable-vote)?

No, [Meek's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek) is one of a few commonly used STV systems. The others are [Warren's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Warren%27s_method) and [Wright's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_system). These are all implementations of the Single Transferable Vote system.

I don't think it's necessary for these specific implementations to have their own tag.

Additionally, I think STV is already a subset of [ranked-choice-voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranked-choice-voting) (see: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting)). I'm not sure if something should change with that tag, but there does seem to be some overlap.

Comment: Concerning the [strategic-voting] tag. I think a [tactical-voting] synonym would be useful. Ngram shows a marked preference for ["strategic voting" over "tactical voting"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strategic+voting%2Ctactical+voting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) since 2000.

Comment: @RickSmith okay, added the synonym. :)